# What is the nmber of different positions of N elements in D positions

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for a general formula that would give me the amount of different P positions that N elements can take with D positions. This N elements are identical so, for exemple (a,b) is the same as (b,a).

**Exemple**

For N = 2 and D = 4
we have : 
[1,1,0,0]
[1,0,1,0]
[1,0,0,1]
[0,1,1,0]
[0,1,0,1]
[0,0,1,1]
wich gives us P = 6 possibilities !

**What I tried**

N= 1 is rather easy, and I found P = D
for N = 2 I found something like P = $$\sum_{i=1}^{D-1} i$$
But when I get to N = 3, it gets tricky and I can't really figure it out. There seems to be something around a sum of a sum, or sum mutliplied by a sum, but I'm not really sure...

There seems to be a pattern, wich make me think that there is a general formula to answer this question. And my math background is not good enough to be able to ask the question in a more former way.

My first goal was to find the solution for N = 4 for and D = 24 for a completely unrelated subject (I'm doing a research project in Neuroscience, wich can explain my poor background in math). But I got stuck at N= 3 and I finelly got intrigued by the question and tried to find a more general answer.

**Supplementary Data**

I took the time to count every possibilities, in an attempt to understand the pattern. If you are interested, this is the series for an incremental amount of D starting at 1

N=1 : [1,2,3,4,5,6...]

N=2 : [0,1,3,6,10,15...]

N=3 : [0,0,1,4,10,20...]

N=4 : [0,0,0,1,5...]

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: I do not fully understand the types of objects you are trying to count as you didn't explain it very well, however the numbers you list at the end are simply [Binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  $\binom{3}{3}=1,\binom{4}{3}=4,\binom{5}{3}=10,\binom{6}{3}=20,\binom{7}{3}=35,\dots$.  It looks like you are simply looking for $\binom{D}{N}$.

Comment: I guess it wasn't clearly explained because I don't know how to explain it in a formal way. It can be boxes, as long as they are identical and you can't make the difference between them. If the Binomial coefficients correspond to the lists, I suppose that this is the answer ! I'm going to look a little bit more to the wikipedia page to make sure but it looks like it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't distinguish the elements, you'll use combinations.

*Taking your example*:
$N$ identical (indistinguishable) objects have to be placed in $N$ boxes chosen from the total of $D$ boxes. What you need is to chose $N$ boxes. The number of possibilities is expressed as the number of $N$-combinations and equals 
$$\binom{D}{N}=\frac{D!}{(D-N)!\;N!}$$ 
In particular, if $\;N=4,\;D=24\;$ there are 
$$\binom{24}{4}=23\times22\times21=10626$$ possibilities.

---

**Note:**
The numbers you give for different values of $N$ in strings are exactly so, e.g. $\binom{5}{3}=10.$